# Understanding JavaScript Styling

Tags: javascript

In the following code, from "[Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](http://www.manning.com/resig/)," why does "Another test." show up in red font?

http://jsfiddle.net/dtHyc/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Suite</title>
    <script>

      (function() {
        var results;
        this.assert = function assert(value, desc) {
          var li = document.createElement("li");
          li.className = value ? "pass" : "fail";
          li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(desc));
          results.appendChild(li);
          if (!value) {
            li.parentNode.parentNode.className = "fail";
          }
          return li;
        };
        this.test = function test(name, fn) {
          results = document.getElementById("results");
          results = assert(true, name).appendChild(
              document.createElement("ul"));
          fn();
        };
      })();

      window.onload = function() {
        test("A test.", function() {
          assert(true, "First assertion completed");
          assert(true, "Second assertion completed");
          assert(true, "Third assertion completed");
        });
        test("Another test.", function() {
          assert(true, "First test completed");
          assert(false, "Second test failed");
          assert(true, "Third assertion completed");
        });
        test("A third test.", function() {
          assert(null, "fail");
          assert(5, "pass")
        });
      };
    </script>
    <style>
      #results li.pass { color: green; }
      #results li.fail { color: red; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="results"></ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Who downvoted this, and why is it not a real question?

Comment: @JosephSilber I think "too localized" is more appropriate.

Comment: @GGG - True, so I voted as such. Still not a reason to downvote.

Comment: @JosephSilber, wasn't me, although it also doesn't show any original research IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since a string is truthy (`"Second test failed" != false`),

```
assert(false, "Second test failed");
```

returns `false`, which invalidates the whole test.

Comment: Thanks, Joseph. That's because of `if (!value) {
            li.parentNode.parentNode.className = "fail";
          }` yea?

Comment: @Kevin - Yes. Or, more simply put, because `(! value) == true`.

Comment: as a side question, what does the `fn()` mean shown in `function test()`?

Comment: @Kevin - That's just the variable that holds the function you pass in as a second argument to `test`.