# How does appendChild work in the context of an assignment?

Tags: javascript

There are a couple of Questions out there related to this same piece of code, including this one: [Understanding JavaScript Styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668814/understanding-javascript-styling)
Again, this is taken from the book [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](http://www.manning.com/resig/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ninja Template</title>
    <style>
      body { background: #d6d6d6; }
      #results li.pass { color: green; }
      #results li.fail { color: red; }
    </style>
  </head>

<body>
  <h2>Test Groups</h2>

  <script>
    (function() {
      var results;

      this.assert = function assert(value, desc) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.className = value ? "pass" : "fail";
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(desc));
        results.appendChild(li);

        if(!value) {
          li.parentNode.parentNode.className = "fail";
        }

        return li;
      }

      this.test = function test(name, fn) {
        results = document.getElementById("results");
        results = assert(true, name).appendChild(   //THIS LINE
          document.createElement("ul"));
        fn();
      }

    })();

    window.onload = function() {
      test("Test Group #1", function() {
        assert(true, "First assertion completed");
        assert(true, "Second assertion completed");
      });

      test("Test Group #2", function() {
        assert(true, "Third assertion completed");
        assert(false, "Fourth assertion completed");
      });
    }

  </script>

  <ul id="results"></ul>
</body>

</html>
```

My question this time is about the line marked with the **THIS LINE comment**, I don't understand how it works. According to my understanding the **assert()** method always returns a **li** tag, and the mentioned line of JS code makes an assignment of that **li** to the parent **ul#results** element, Wouldn't that convert that **ul#results** into a **li** tag and break the desired structure? (Obviously it doesn't, and I'm puzzled as to why is that)

*Does an assignment work as an append in pure JS?*

I don't understand how this works at all, any help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: I wish that was all I needed to understand what happens in that line of code. Could you please elaborate further?

Comment: No problem @iccthedral. Thank you for taking the time nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.appendChild` **returns the child**, in this case a `ul`, so it is setting `results` to be the newly inserted `ul`.

```
<ul id="results">
   <li>
       <ul></ul> <!-- this is now results -->
   </li>
</ul>
```

Each `test()` call appends an `li` to `#results`; inside each `test` are two `assert` calls which now append their generated `li` elements into the newly inserted `ul` seen above.

```
this.test = function test(name, fn) {
    // new test; set _results_ to the outermost UL, ul#results
    results = document.getElementById("results");

    // next line appends an LI to #results, 
    // appends a new UL to that LI, and sets _results_ to the new UL
    results = assert(true, name).appendChild(document.createElement("ul"));

    // the assert() calls in the callback are now called 
    // with _results_ referring to the nested UL
    fn();
  }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6kGa2/)

Comment: Holly Molly, I thought ids within the DOM were supposed to be unique. Anyways, I get that part, but the assignment is truly the point that still makes that line 'obfuscated' because I thought results = document.getElementById("results"); would always get outer-most ul. can you explain why THAT's NOT the case? Thank you for your answer sir.

Comment: IDs are unique. Don't confuse the element with ID `#results` and the _variable_ `results`. Look at the `onload` function which runs the tests, and then the methods themselves. Each time `test()` is called, it sets `results` to `#results`. It then calls `assert` (with `results` still referring to the outer `ul#results`) which appends an `li` and returns it. A new `ul` is appended to __that__ `li`, and `results` is set to that appended `ul` __until `test()` is called again__. Does that make sense?

Comment: I added some inline comments; see if that helps.

Comment: `results = document.getElementById("results");` absolutely __does__ get the outermost UL every time, but that only happens on each `test`, __NOT__ each `assert`.

Comment: Fantastic explanation, I GOT IT! this inline comment: (// appends a new UL to that LI, and sets _results_ to the new UL) did it,
THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH, SIR!